# Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 19 not available

Tags: android, maven

### I have a working Android app. When I run this command: mvn clean package, I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.1:generate-sources
>   (default-generate-sources)
>   on project spring-android-showcase-client:
>   Execution  default-generate-sources of goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.1:generate-sources
>   failed: Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 19 not available.
>   This command
>   should give you all you need: C:\tools\android update sdk --no-ui
>   --obsolete --force

Can someone help how to solve this?

Comment: Well, you should probably install SDK for API 19..

Comment: How to install API 19?

Comment: @yuva I try this link but it does not work!

Comment: @Samantha Open Sdk Manager and download SDK and image file.