# mvn install: Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 23 not available

Tags: android, maven

I get the following error when attempting to install maven, with "mvn clean install" command:

```
Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.2.1:
generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project compatibility-v7-gridlayout: 
Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.2.1:
generate-sources failed: Invalid SDK: 
Platform/API level 23 not available. This command should give you all you need:
D:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\android 
update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force
```

I ran the command suggested, with no effect.

Looking in the Android SDK Manager, I see that I have Android SDK Platform-tools 23.0.1, Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.1.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling these, with no effect.

Environment variables are set so:

```
set M2_HOME=D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3  
set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin  
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.simpligility.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>progressive-organization-pom</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</parent>
   ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <sdk>
            <platform>${android.sdk.platform}</platform>
          </sdk>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I have read:
[Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 19 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705442/invalid-sdk-platform-api-level-19-not-available)
[MAVEN Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 16 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638699/maven-invalid-sdk-platform-api-level-16-not-available)
One suggestion there is to set the  to a specific number, whereas the existing code in the pom uses `${android.sdk.platform}`, which I think would be better, i.e. more maintainable. Regardless, changing it to 23 has no effect.

Windows 7

What can I do?

Edit ---------------------------------------
Changing the maven version in the pom file to `<version>3.3.3</version>` causes this error:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for com.simpligility.android.sdk-deployer:maven-android-sdk-deployer:2.8.0: 
Failure to find com.simpligility.maven:progressive-organization-pom:pom:3.3.3 
in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
```

Comment: Please check your android SDK home path. Also mention the maven version in pom.xml file

Comment: Added maven version from pom file. The value of the android SDK home path is stated in the original question.

Comment: Try to update your maven

Comment: I already have the latest version of maven, 3.3.3. On your suggestion, I've changed the version in the pom. See Edit in the original question for the error I now get.

Comment: Changing the maven version in the pom file back to `3.0.0` and following instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache), issuing this command: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false`, I get BUILD SUCCESS. I cannot say that I understand what this did.